# Is there a way to make Org mode ignore src blocks when exporting to html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I have an org document with scattered with source blocks that I'd like excluded when I export the file to html.

Is there a variable or option I can set which will ignore the src blocks?

I have tried using the noexport as shown below but the code still appears in the resultant html.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC json :noexport:
{ ... }
#+END_SRC
```

Thanks!

Comment: `:exports none` should do it.

Comment: @mutbuerger: Could you maybe make an answer out of that?  It really is the preferred solution.  It can be combined with header-argument defaults, so that all source blocks' export can be controlled with only one setting, and no emacs lisp code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A solution that doesn't depend on `org-export-filter-src-block-functions` and gives you more flexibility is using the `:exports` header argument (see `(info "(org) Exporting code blocks")`). Setting the argument to `:exports none` results in neither the code block nor its results being exported.

If you prefer a backend specific rule, you may use a conditional as the argument:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :exports (when (eq org-export-current-backend 'html) "none")
(+ 1 2)
#+end_src
```

Comment: While the accepted solution works if all src blocks in an org file need to be excluded, this solution works if only certain src blocks are to be excluded. This is more customizable without creating additional functions.

Comment: Neat! Is this use of lisp code as header argument value documented?

Comment: I'm not sure, but a look at `org-babel-merge-params` makes this pretty obvious. For the `:results` there is even an explicit `(if (stringp value) value (eval value t))` ... for whatever reason.

Answer (score 10):

Based on section [12.15](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html#Advanced-configuration) of org documentation:

```
(defun my-html-filter-src-blocks (text backend info)
  "Remove source blocks from html export."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    "[removed source block]"))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
         'my-html-filter-src-blocks)
```

Replace "[removed source block]" with an empty string of course!

Comment: This works globally too which is great. Thanks!